# Efficient way to do math operation between Numpy rows

Tags: python, performance, numpy

The idea is to substract between rows in `Numpy array`.

Here,list comprehension is proposed. But, I wonder whether there is more efficient and fast.

Currently, the proposed solution is slow when given a large `arr`

```
import numpy as np
nfreq=500
arr=np.array([[11850,0,1],
[12310,0,3],
[13924,0,4],
[16690,0,1],
[17082,0,3],
[18746,0,4],
[21956,0,2],
[22324,0,3],
[23694,0,4],
[25382,0,1],
[25776,0,3],
[28592,0,4],
[31676,0,2],
[32028,0,3],
[33498,0,4]])
trange = np.where(arr == 3)[0]
val=[(arr[x,0],(arr[x,0]-arr[x-1,0])/nfreq,(arr[x+1,0]-arr[x,0])/nfreq) for x in trange]
val=np.array(val)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the vectorial equivalent, however as there are 3 separate operation, there is still a bottleneck in merging them into the final array. Efficiency will depend on the number of rows.

```
np.array([arr[trange, 0],
          (arr[trange, 0]-arr[trange-1, 0])/nfreq,
          (arr[trange+1, 0]-arr[trange, 0])/nfreq]).T
```

output:

```
array([[1.2310e+04, 9.2000e-01, 3.2280e+00],
       [1.7082e+04, 7.8400e-01, 3.3280e+00],
       [2.2324e+04, 7.3600e-01, 2.7400e+00],
       [2.5776e+04, 7.8800e-01, 5.6320e+00],
       [3.2028e+04, 7.0400e-01, 2.9400e+00]])
```

Comment: This is event better

Comment: Note that storing `arr[trange, 0]` in a temporary variable should be a bit faster because Numpy will not recompute it 3 times.

Comment: @Jérôme that's true, but don't expect a spectacular change, slicing here would be ~1µs, so non noticeable for only 3 variables ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```py
a = arr[trange, 0]
b = (arr[trange, 0] - arr[trange-1, 0])/nfreq
c = (arr[trange+1, 0] - arr[trange, 0])/nfreq

output = np.stack((a,b,c), axis=1)

# array([[1.2310e+04, 9.2000e-01, 3.2280e+00],
#        [1.7082e+04, 7.8400e-01, 3.3280e+00],
#        [2.2324e+04, 7.3600e-01, 2.7400e+00],
#        [2.5776e+04, 7.8800e-01, 5.6320e+00],
#        [3.2028e+04, 7.0400e-01, 2.9400e+00]])
```

Comment: I think this is almost the same with https://stackoverflow.com/a/69120753/6446053 ? am I?